# How to get ONLY the variable output of a PSQL statement

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql

If have a variable:

```
var=$(psql -U chh1 -d crewdb -c '\t' -c "SELECT MAX(date_linkid) + 1 FROM date_link;")
```

When I run:

```
echo "$var"
```

I get:

```
Tuples only is on.
      284
```

How can I write the variable statement so I only get the number 284?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common method is to use the `-A` and `-t` options of psql to remove blank padding and any meta-information around results.

For example:

```
prompt$ count=$(psql -At -d postgres -c "select count(*) from pg_database")
prompt$ echo $count
19
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this using [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) *parameter expansion*:

```
echo "${var##* }"
```

Comment: Thanks Gilles. It works.